# Missing chars when posting data in ajax using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a textarea:

```
<textarea id="my_text"></textarea>
```

And have some ajax code in javascript like this:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var my_text = document.getElementById("my_text").value;
xmlhttp.open("POST", ".", true);
xmlhttp.send("my_text=" + my_text + "&foo=1");
```

When I filled the textarea with string `abc +1 +2 +3`, and run the JS code. The value of "my_text" I get in the server side is `abc  1  2  3`.

How can I change the JS code to get the right string `abc +1 +2 +3` in server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `encodeURIComponent(my_text)` to prepare your text for submission. This function should always be used for parameters, to properly escape characters. You have already experienced an occasion where your code breaks.
Another aweful result of not escaping the characters occurs when the user uses a `&` in his string, effectively creating an extra parameter.

```
xmlhttp.send("my_text=" + encodeURIComponent(my_text) + "&foo=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `escape` function.

> xmlhttp.send("my_text=" + escape(my_text) + "&foo=1");

You were loosing characters because the + sign is a reserved HTTP character -- which evaluates to a space (' ').

**EDIT:** Very true, escape won't work in this case as it will replace spaces, but not plus symbols, with their hex representations. Sorry for the mix up (blush)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems escape doesn't work in this situation. I still missing '+' if I use escape.